# How to get instruction length

Tags: c

here is code for continuing when segv, I don't understand "6 bytes", why is 6?

```
static void sigaction_segv(int signal, siginfo_t *si, void *arg) {
    ucontext_t *ctx = (ucontext_t *) arg;
    /* We are on linux x86, the returning IP is stored in RIP (64bit) or EIP (32bit).
       In this example, the length of the offending instruction is 6 bytes.
       So we skip the offender ! */
#if __WORDSIZE == 64
    printf("Caught SIGSEGV, addr %p, RIP 0x%lx\n", si->si_addr, ctx->uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_RIP]);
    ctx->uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_RIP] += 6;
#else
    printf("Caught SIGSEGV, addr %p, EIP 0x%x\n", si->si_addr, ctx->uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_EIP]);
        ctx->uc_mcontext.gregs[REG_EIP] += 6;
#endif
}
```

full code is [here](https://gist.github.com/roroco/6a8e4ef13413c0cc2f56)

Comment: It depends on what compiler you're using and with what optimization flags you compiled with... and ultimately the code it's meant to be overridding.  Apparently `*(int *) NULL = 0;` takes up 6 bytes to encode... for some compiler and for some optimization flags...

Comment: Did you note the line: *In this example, the length of the offending instruction is 6 bytes.*  So, IN THIS EXAMPLE, the length of the instruction is 6 bytes.  In reality, the cold would need to calculate the actual length of the instruction and use that actual length for the adjustment, rather than a hardcoded '6'

Comment: Note: trying to continue the execution of the code after a seg fault event is a very bad idea..  Much better to fix the root cause of the problem, then re-compile, re-link, and re-run the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
*(int *) NULL = 0;
```

will compile to (after clearing rax):

```
c7 00 00 00 00 00       ' movl   $0x0,(%rax)
```

so that's 6 bytes of machine code.
Use objdump to see the assembly of your code.

Comment: can you tell me how to convert "*(int *) NULL = 0;" to "c7 00 00 00 00 00       ' movl   $0x0,(%rax)"?

Comment: That is the task of your compiler and assembler. Put this C statement in main() in a new file. Compile it with cc -c main.c -o main.o Then do objdump -d main.o to disassemble it and there you will find the line. The c7 00 00 00 00 00 is the machine code instruction.

Comment: Also, as mentioned by  user3629249, this segv code is for multiple reasons very bad and should never be used in a real program. Use it only to learn about how exceptions (signals) work.